# jQuery .each() returns DOM element and not a jQuery object

Tags: dom, jquery-selectors, jquery

I could be misunderstanding what is happening but from what I can tell I am getting a DOM element and not a jQuery object when I use `.each()`.

The below will not work as `this` refers to a DOM element and not a jQuery object

```
$("span[id$='_TotalItemCost']").each(function() {
    var someText = this.text();
});
```

Modified to transform `this` to a jQuery object and all is well

```
$("span[id$='_TotalItemCost']").each(function() {
    var someText = $(this).text();
});
```

Is there something funky with my selector? Is the [jQuery `.each()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/each/) wrong and it's not a jQuery object but rather a DOM element returned by `.each()`?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The documention is not wrong but you may misunderstand what a jQuery object is.

The jQuery object is returned by the `$()` function. So `$("span[id$='_TotalItemCost']")` is one jQuery object which contains every span element selected.

Using `.each()` will iterate over the elements contained in the jQuery object. This is why this is a DOM node and not a jQuery object.

You did the right thing by using `$(this)` to use the jQuery methods on this specific element.

Comment: Futher, jQuery objects are heavier than the DOM object itself - some of us don't want extra fluff if we're after something simple..

Comment: Awesome, just found this tidbit in the documentation which I had missed *the callback is fired in the context of the current DOM element, so the keyword `this` refers to the element.*

Comment: $(expression).each(..) does return the jquery instance for chaining.  This is probably what the jquery documentation is referring to.

Comment: Right - the distinction between what `.each()` returns, and what context the callback runs with.  Tripped me up at first as well.

Answer (score 5):

@Vincent Robert, you pretty much summarized it perfectly, but let me just extend that a little.

even though JQuery is a function with prototypes extending its root instance, its acts more like an object.

if you seperate objects from methods/functions and look at them individually you will then understand how the jQuery interface is built.

si think of `$()` as an object, and think of `each()` as a method. you initialize an object using the jQuery `$()` "selector", witch in turn returns an objects that contains only the elemetns / data you selected from the selector `$()`.

this then has methods / functions that you can run directly on the selected content, but methods should not return a jquery object because most of the time there not returning nodes but mere strings or boolean's, so having them wrapped in a jQuery object would be pointless.

as your OP is based around the each function, your not meant to receive a jquery object there because each is not specifically designed for nodes and elements as such

for example, would you want a jquery object here?

```
$({a:'1',b:'2'}).each(function(){
});
```

this would be bad right, and pointless, that's why methods do/should not return objects, unless the method is meaning to return a singleton or is specifically designed for object returning.

also, when I say object, im not talking about json objects as such, but method / prototyping objects.

Hope this helps out.